# Expand the output of the command and only then assign it to a variable

Tags: bash, shell, variable-assignment

Consider this task : **With a one line command** save all usernames transformed into CAPITALS in a bash array called USERNAMES. **Capitalize using bash variable expansion**.

If not for the the one line limitation, I would just use

```
USERNAMES=($(ls /home)) # simplified for purposes of this question, returns (user1 user2 ...)
USERNAMES=(${USERNAMES[*]^^}) # must return (USER1 USER2 ...)
```

but all attempts at nesting the first assignment to the variable expansion like `USERNAMES=${($(ls /home))^^}` or similar lead to 'bad substitution' error. I'm using bash 4.4.20(1)-release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `/*` because you should not parse `ls` and I have only one dir in home.

```
USERNAMES=(/*); USERNAMES=("${USERNAMES[@]^^}")
readarray -t USERNAMES < <(printf "%s\n" /* | sed 's/.*/\U&/')
readarray -t USERNAMES < <(printf "%s\n" /* | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')
# or zero separated
readarray -t -d '' USERNAMES < <(printf "%s\0" /* | sed -z 's/.*/\U&/')
readarray -t -d '' USERNAMES < <(printf "%s\0" /* | tr -z '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')
# Or another program
readarray -t USERNAMES < <(python -c 'import os,sys;[print(x.upper()) for x in os.listdir(sys.argv[1])]' /)
# You can hash _any_ multiline script to base64 and then execute it. It will be one line.
base64 -d <<<IyEvYmluL2Jhc2gKVVNFUk5BTUVTPSgkKGxzIC9ob21lKSkgIyBzaW1wbGlmaWVkIGZvciBwdXJwb3NlcyBvZiB0aGlzIHF1ZXN0aW9uLCByZXR1cm5zICh1c2VyMSB1c2VyMiAuLi4pClVTRVJOQU1FUz0oJHtVU0VSTkFNRVNbKl1eXn0pICMgbXVzdCByZXR1cm4gKFVTRVIxIFVTRVIyIC4uLikKZWNobyAiJHtVU0VSTkFNRVNbQF19Igo= | bash
```

Notes:

- do not parse ls! https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead
- Do not use `($(...))`. Use `readarray`
- When working with arrays, properly quote and use `[@]`. It's `"${USERNAMES[@]}"`.

Comment: is there no other way? I considered this, but simply splitting one line into two using ; feels like cheating

Comment: @P.Janecek and don't capitalize your variable names

Comment: This works, but I was looking for a one line solution (this is required, since it is a homework). Also, I plan to get the user list from /etc/passwd, but I used ls /home in this question, because it primarily focuses on something else

Comment: If it's homework, I would go with `ls /home | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'`

Comment: I bolded the requirements that have to be met in the original question

Comment: Anyway, no, it's impossible to do `($(ls /home))^^}` or anything similar. You have to write it.

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks for the confirmation, your answer is acceptable then, if original conditions can't be met

Answer (score 0):

If this is for homework, I'm guessing your teacher is looking for

```
users=($(ls /home | tr a-z A-Z))
```

or perhaps, to [avoid parsing `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) (but consequently not strictly sticking to the "one command only" requirement)

```
users=($(cd /home && echo * | tr a-z A-Z))
```

Bash has built-in [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) facilities but those necessarily require two commands - one to get the value and another to perform a parameter expansion on it.